# Unity 2d Video Player сильно тормозит

Tags: android, unity3d-android, unity3d, unity3d-ui

Есть отельная сцена только с  canvas со sprite внутри у которого есть компонент видеоплеера. **На компьютере** все работает без проблем, но при экспорте в apk и установе **на телефоне** видео ***глючит*** ОЧЕНЬ сильно (разница между кадрами несколько секунд, из аудио проигрывается несколько очень маленьких отрывков-звуков)

Параметры видео:
Размер 17МБ
Разрешение 1920*1080
Битрейт 5500 кбит/с
Аудио включено
30 кадров/с
Длится 30 с

Comment: А если для эксперимента снизить качество видеоролика с FullHD на что-нибудь менее тяжелое. И еще могут быть проблемы с кодеками.
Попробуйте сохранить ролик в разных вариантах (с разными кодеками). И протестировать на девайсе.

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский Вы оказались правы. Установил разрешение пониже, прогнав через ffmpeg. Кажется проблема именно в кодировке, а не в разрешениеи, прогон через ffmpeg помогает

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский Нет, неправ. Только при уменьшении размера до ~ 850:480 начал воспроизводиться нормально. Avi не воспроизводит. Есть идеи как все же воспроизвести fullHd видео?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Видео поддерживаются, наверное, любые популярные, но главное в настройках Player>Android>Other Settings убрать галку multithreading rendering. Тогда все нормально проигрывается.